# Choice of model surrogate for bayesian optimization

Tags: supervised-learning, hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization

I am running BayesSearchCV to optimize the hyperparameters of my machine learning model. This particular procedure allows the user to choose the surrogate model. The options are Gaussian Process, Random Forest, Extra Trees, and Gradient-Boosted Regression Trees. How should my understanding of the hyperparameter space guide my decision as to which surrogate to use? Are there other special considerations to make?

Comment: Great question. Gaussian processes are the most data-efficient (i.e. should require fewer machine learning model fits in total), but makes very serious smoothness assumptions, viz. that the (expected) performance of your model for two similar hyperparameter configurations will likewise be similar. If this is not the case, a tree-based method will do better.

Comment: @JohnMadden it seems like this comment could be expanded to an answer.